# Issue on woocommerce search on user login

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Firstly, we install the `woocommerce` plugin then we add user roles.

When we login as a user and search any product then its works fine but when we search product which are not included in the products like abc or xyz then error mesaage will be shown means its work fine also  But when we login as a user 12 to 14 times and then search the products which are not included my shop page then issue occurred or  no error message will be shown like 'No products were found' and footer dissappear.

We also clear browser cache but nothing will be happened and same issue ocuured.

Comment: did you clear the cookies also.....

Comment: yes i clear all cookies

Comment: Sounds like an error is stopping everything .. is there anything in the PHP error logs? Do you have display errors turned on?

Comment: Dear @amna kausar,
if any cache  plugin in ur site than remove and try.